# Is there a way to perform scrolling in Material UI (MUI) table through Selenium or Javascript?

Tags: selenium, material-ui, mui-datatable

Is there any way *through Selenium or Javascript* to perform a horizontal scrolling in MUI table?
Due lazy loading it's impossible to perform **Actions** to element that does not exist, i.e. element I'm looking for that's not in the DOM yet.
Example of situation:
Imagine I have columns from A...Z but only A...F are visible and in the DOM and column Z will be in the DOM only after scrolling to the end of right side.

I already tried increasing **scrollHeigh** in a scrollable element (*.MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller*) in order to perform scrolling. It increases without exception, but does not perform a real scrolling.
I also tried **scrollIntoView** to last cell/column but it's not enough to lazy loading call rendering for next column.
Scroller element does not accept sendKeys, though. Hence no Keys.RIGHT acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here,I've used some tricky loop with scrollintoview inside to count all the rows, but want to replace it with something smarter...(one liner)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mui element with virtual scroller can be scrolled using scrollLeft (horizontally) and scrollTop (vertically)

set number of pixels to scroll.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollleft.asp

document
.getElementsByClassName('MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller')[0]
.scrollLeft